# Keeping pointers to subviews

Tags: objective-c, uiview

Subviews added to a view are automatically retained by the view. Suppose you want to have a separate pointer to the same subview so you don't need to constantly retrieve it via its tag.

What type of `@property` is necessary for such a case? I assume that setting the property to `retain` is not a good idea since the main view is already retaining it? Should it be `assign`?

Or, is using `@property` entirely unnecessary here unless you plan to re-assign it later or refer to it with dot notation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either `retain` or `assign`.

Of course, if you use `retain`, you have to set the property to `nil` or release its object in `viewDidUnload` and `dealloc`.

The reason some people prefer `retain` is because it means the property is still valid in `viewDidUnload`.  So if you have other cleanup to do, and that cleanup requires the view to still exist, you can do it in `viewDidUnload`.

If you use `assign`, you don't have to set the property to `nil` in `viewDidUnload` and `dealloc` (though it would be good practice).  However, by the time you receive `viewDidUnload`, the view has already been released, so you can't use it at that point for other cleanup.  Instead you have to override `didReceiveMemoryWarning` to do the cleanup before calling `[super didReceiveMemoryWarning]`.

In iOS 5.0, you can do the cleanup in `viewWillUnload` instead of overriding `didReceiveMemoryWarning`.

Comment: good explanation; and I suppose I don't need to use a property at all, just a regular ivar, if i need only a pointer and will not be setting it from other classes using dot notation, right

Comment: You only need to use a property if you want to expose it outside your class.  Dot notation is irrelevant.  If you declare the properly-named getter and/or setter methods, you can use the dot notation without an `@property` declaration.

Comment: If I declare the properly-named getter and/or setter methods without using `@property` then the ivars are still exposed outside my class, right?

Comment: Yes.  If you have setter/getter methods for an ivar, then by definition the ivar is exposed (to the extent that the getter/setter work in a straightforward way).  It doesn't matter whether you used `@property` to declare them or declared them the old-fashioned way.

Answer (score 2):

Consider these two things:

1. There's no problem with retaining an object several times provided that each retain is balanced with release. With respect to properties, this just means that you should set your property to nil when you're done with it.
2. The basic idea behind memory management in Objective-C is that you worry about retaining the objects that you're using and let other objects worry about the objects that they're using.

Considering these, I'd advocate using retain. If you rely on he fact that a view retains its subviews, you've suddenly made your code dependant on external behavior. I'm not saying that UIView is likely to stop retaining its subviews, but if you keep a non-retained reference to a subview and later remove that subview from its superview you're code is likely to crash.

Some folks do use assign for outlets pointing to subviews when they know those subviews will never be removed. Personally, I don't see the point of relying on another object to retain something for you when retaining that thing yourself is so simple and cheap.